# Why does SOLRJ fail with undefined field error

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm using SOLRJ library.

```
query.setQuery("content_raw:born");
query.setParam("df", "content");
query.setParam("hl", "true");
QueryResponse solrResponse = server.query(query);
```

And I get `undefined field content_raw` error.

But when I hit the URL that get's generated (I got it from the logs) in a browser, it works.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/testCollection/select?
q=content_raw%3Aborn
&df=content
&hl=true
```

Any Idea on why this strange behaviour.

My schema.xml

```
<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true"
        multiValued="true" />
<field name="content_raw" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"
        multiValued="true" />
<copyField source="content" dest="content_raw" />
```

Comment: Which fields are defined in your schema.xml? Is content_raw among these fields? If so, is it indexed=true?

Comment: yes. if not, how come I get result when I hit the URL?

Comment: Your SolrJ query might use a different defType than when you query through the web interface. Maybe you're searching for content_raw:born in a different field. Check the Solr log for what the actual query is. It's also weird to use `df` to point to a field that's not indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the problem that your solrserver url used in creating server instance might be wrong as it uses collection1 by default. You have to specify solr-core in server as `testCollection`.
After that it will work fine for sure.

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem.